# How to copy text untill newline character?

Tags: c, arrays, text, char

I have a char array `list` that contains text from a text file, for example:

```
this is the first line
this is the second line
```

I want to have the first line copied to another char array without \n (and/or \r).

I do not know the size of the first line exactly but I do know it is less than 100 bytes.

Snappet of my code:

```
unsigned char *line;
line = (u_char *)calloc(100, sizeof(char));

//read txt file to list

while(list[0] != '\n'){
    line[0] = list[0];
    list++;
    line++;
}
```

Unfortunaly line is empty. Note that I know for sure list isn't empty, and contains the text as showed above.

Any suggestions on this code, or another solution? The file is opened using `open()` and not `fopen()` so I've to loop through my list array.

Comment: One suggestion is don't change `line`, which is you reference to the memory returned by `calloc`.  Have you shown that `list` actually contains the data from the file?  You could try using an index to the two arrays: `for(int n = 0; (n < 100) && (list[n] !='\r') && (list[n] != '\n'); n++){ line[n] = list[n]; }`

Comment: @MikeofSST Thanks for noticing, and +1 for the build in error avoiding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
for ( int i = 0; list[i] && list[i] != '\n'; ++i ) {
    line[i] = list[i];
}
```

Comment: Much better, agreed. But that will still run off the end of a string that has no new-line characters. :-)

Comment: @MOehm: Per OP, "Note that I know for sure list isn't empty, and contains the text as showed above."

Comment: Touché. I misread the "line is empty", which means the result, not the input. (I still think a null check would make the code more generally applicable beyond the OP assertions.)

Comment: Yep this is it, thanks. I grabbed this code from somewhere else (and modified is) so I assumed it would work, though I might had done it this way when making it myself. Thanks again!

Comment: @MOehm: Agree, added null check.

Answer (score 1):

You also could use `strcspn()` from the [standard library](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.14.html#strcspn) `string.h`:

> Declaration:
>
> ```
> size_t strcspn(const char *str1, const char *str2);
> ```
>
> Finds the first sequence of characters in the string str1 that does
>   not contain any character specified in str2.
>
> Returns the length of this first sequence of characters found that do
>   not match with str2.
>   [Source](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.14.html#strcspn)

Your program would then become

```
unsigned char *line;
int firstlineLength;

//read txt file to list

/*count the characters up to first linebreak */
firstlineLength = strspn(list, "\n"); 
/* allocate just the memory you need +1 one for the terminating zero*/
line = (u_char *)calloc(firstlineLength+1, sizeof(char));
strncpy(line, list, firstlineLength);
```